# Undefined method for class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm creating a class. I'm pulling data from a hash named `ROLL_CALL`. The `all` method should return an array of `Team` objects.

```
require_relative "./team_data"
class Team
  attr_reader :name
  def intialize (name)
    @name = name
    def all
      all_teams = []
      TeamData::ROLL_CALL.each do |team, info|
        all_teams << Team.new(team)
      end
      all_teams
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to call `Team.all`, I get the undefined method for `all`.

Comment: Do you really want to add `all` inside `initialize` or is it a typo?

Comment: put the specific error in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't structured correctly. That `def all` should be at the top-level and declared as a class-style method. There's also some other things worth fixing:

```
require_relative "./team_data"

class Team
  def self.all
    TeamData::ROLL_CALL.map do |team, info|
      Team.new(team)
    end
  end

  attr_reader :name

  def intialize (name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Use `map` instead of creating a temporary array and jamming things into it with `each` only to return it in the end, as that's exactly what `map` does for you.

Comment: That did get rid of the undefined method but now I'm getting a separate error when I try to run Team.all. It's telling me I have the wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0). Sorry if these are simple questions still a relative newbie to Ruby.

Comment: @Gingervitus Nothing wrong with being new, but it sounds like you're using a method in a way different than in your question or as defined here. This has no arguments, so if you're calling `Team.all(1)` it will error out like that. If you're not sure what to do, open a new question with any relevant details.